# show and hide primefaces tab via ajax depending on selectOneMenu's values - Hide a tab without update the tabview

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a problem with `p:tab`. I googled a lot, but found nothing about this issue.

I need to show/Hide a `tab` within a `tabView` based on selection of a `selectOneMenu` value. So, I have used ajax but the problem is that when I change the value of `selectOneMenu` all form inputs are reset and values are lost.

```html
<p:tab id="informationTab">     
  <h:outputLabel for="situationFamiliale" value="Situation  familiale: *" />
  <p:selectOneMenu id="situationFamiliale" value="#{bean.entity.attribut}" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Celibataire" itemValue="Celibataire" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Marie(e)" itemValue="Marie(e)" />
    <f:ajax event="change" render="@form" />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:tab>

<p:tab id="id" rendered="#{bean.entity.attribut== 'Marie(e)'}" title="Information Menage">

</p:tab>
```

Comment: Try just updating the tab (`update="id"`) instead of re-rendering the whole form (`render="@form"`).

Comment: I have already tried this solution but in this case my tab don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<f:ajax` without `execute=`, the default for `execute`is '@this'. Therefore only the value of the SelectOneMenu is sent to the server. Because of `render="@form"` the whole form will be rerendered and all other changes are lost.

You should use `f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"...>`. The problem is, you have to rerender the whole tabview if you want to appear/disappear a tab. You can't rerender a single tab with a rendered attribut.

Comment: this is my problem, I do want to update a tab without the entire tabView.it must exist a solution,no?

Comment: that's only possible, if the tab may stay in the tabview, but is empty.
`<p:tab id="tabid"><h:panelGroup rendered="#{myRenderingCondition}">`.
Now you can use `<f:ajax render="tabid"`. If your `render=` resides in a different tab, you'll probably have to use `render=":formid:tabid".